# datetime conversion to other format in php

Tags: php, datetime, datetimepicker

I was trying to convert a datetime to another format.

```
 $original_value = "10-30-2013 14:19:12";
```

It is in **m-d-Y H:i:s** format and i want to convert it into **Y-m-d H:i:s** to save it to the database.

I've already tried the ff:

```
 $original_value = "10-30-2013 14:19:12";
 $date = new DateTime(strtotime($original_value));
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

 output: 2013-10-16 14:31:19
 // which is wrong since it gets the current datetime value
```

---

```
 $original_value = "10-30-2013 14:19:12";
 echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($original_value))

 output: 1970-01-01 08:00:00
 // which is also invalid
```

How can i do this kind of thing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Same with my second solution, you just changed the H to h. I need H to save it in 24 Hour Format

Comment: yea, seee the answer below..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat):

```
$original_value = '10-30-2013 14:19:12';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', $original_value);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

My Way is to separate the year month day and time in advance. Then reformat it according to the standard time format. My code is as follows:

```
echo "<br>";
echo $original_value = "10-30-2013 14:19:12";
echo "<br>";
$tmp_array=explode("-",$original_value);
echo $month=$tmp_array[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $day=$tmp_array[1];
echo "<br>";
$tmp_array=explode(" ",$tmp_array[2]);
echo $year=$tmp_array[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $time=$tmp_array[1];
echo "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($year."-".$month."-".$day." ".$time));
```

Comment: sorry erick, your code can be simplified with the one above. thank you for the effort :D